# Google App Script Properties Service | Security and Property lifetime

Tags: google-apps-script

The docs for the App Scripts Properties service don't give specifics on who can see what properties and how long the properties are saved.

What I'm wanting to do is have my web app give tokens to users to basically "initialize" a GSheet with paid features. Rather than go through a whole login flow, I'm thinking I can just have users input the token in a prompt and then use the User Property to save the token.

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
userProperties.setProperty('token', token)
```

What I'm not sure of is it safe or not to basically save a long lived bearer token as a property here? Is there any way it could be accessible to another user? Is that property saved for the life of the gSheet?

Comment: Mostly safe, I believe. I don't think this property is easily accessible by other users. One way, I could think of is by accessing the execution transcript, if the script was just run by the original user. Note that You need edit access to get into the script editor. AFAIK, The property lives as long as the script lives.

Answer (score 1):

> *The docs for the App Scripts Properties service don't give specifics on who can see what properties and how long the properties are saved.*

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores
2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas
3. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service